# set select options from JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get the following JSON returned from a JQUERY getJSON call:

```
{                               
"status": "Succes",             
"type": "GPS",                  
"serial": "40332",              
"crat": "C3",                   
"ata": "34",                    
"time": "0",                    
"dates": ["30/09/14","01/10/14"]
}
```

**I want to iterate through the dates and set a select drop down with the date values.**

I am happy to do this in standard JavaScript or JQuery.

I have tried a number of options but none seem to work.

The page has this section of code:

```
<select name="adddate">
  <option value="---">--- Select A Date ---</option>
</select>
```

In my javascript in the getJSON success function this is the latest code I tried.

```
var strDates = data.dates;       
var arrayDates = new Array();    
arrayDates = strDates.split(",");
```

I have tried other methods but none have worked and I have removed them now.

I have code that sets other inputs with the other items in the JSON data and that is working.

It is just extracting the array of dates and adding each item as an option for the select that I cannot figure out.

Comment: show us your html also... and what you have tried

Comment: Please update this post with one of the attempts you have used...

Comment: also provide better definition of what `set a dropdown` means. Create options? Set values?

Comment: you already have an array and `split()` is a string function. Wasn't any need to try to create another array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var select = $('select[name=adddate]');
$.each( data.dates, function(i, date) {
  select.append( $('<option/>',{text:date}) );
});
```

```js
var data = {                               
"status": "Succes",             
"type": "GPS",                  
"serial": "40332",              
"crat": "C3",                   
"ata": "34",                    
"time": "0",                    
"dates": ["30/09/14","01/10/14"]
},
    select = $('select[name=adddate]');
$.each( data.dates, function(i, date) {
  select.append( $('<option/>',{text:date}) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="adddate">
</select>
```

Comment: Answer accepted now.  This is the first time I have used stack overflow so I didn't know I had to do that.  thank you for advising me on that too.